# Error VSP1011: Unable to obtain debug information. Link with the /Profile linker switch

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, profiling

I am trying to profile a mixed mode program with instrumentation.

For one of the dlls I get:

```
Error VSP1011: Unable to obtain debug information. Link with the /Profile linker switch.
PRF0002: Instrumentation failed with these options: /u "C:\Utc\bin\x64\Release\oqpers.dll"   /excludesmallfuncs.  Please check the output window for additional details.
```

When I look under Linker/Advanced for the project I do see:

Yes (/PROFILE)

Any other ideas?

Comment: Which toolchain actually?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017, but we are compiling with the 2013 toolchain.

Comment: For this project, platform toolset = "Visual Studio 2013 (v120)"

Answer (score 0):

I found this link:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80750/analyze-c-performance-prf0002-instrumentation-fail.html

This answer looks good.

**Here is the answer below:**

I had to use the 64 bit visual studio 2013 version of vsinstr.exe

First, this is a bug in the VS2017 version of VSInstr.exe. The problem is that it cannot instrument binaries built with the VS2013 toolset. If I recall correctly, there was a change that occurred in the PDB reader components that make the newer reader not read PDBs produced by older tools. In this scenario the older toolset is being used to produce the binary and PDB, but the newer VSInstr.exe is being used to attempt the instrumentation. The newer VSInstr uses the newer PDB reader and it fails to read the PDB produced by the older tools. There's nothing you can do on your end to fix this problem, but I can suggest a workaround.

To workaround this problem, you can revert to using the older VSInstr.exe from the command line. The older VSInstr.exe can read the PDB produced by the older toolset and instrumentation is successful. I tried this on my system and it works for me. Here are the 6 steps for you to try:

Open a VS2013 developer command prompt as an administrator. (All subsequent operations occur in this admin cmd prompt.)
Instrument the target application. In this case I navigated to the InstrumentationDemoApp\Release folder, then typed "vsinstr terrain.exe /excludesmallfuncs". The instrumentation should indicate success.
Start the profiler monitor with the following command: "vsperfcmd /start:trace /out:test.vsp". This will launch the background monitor which will collect the trace information as it is emitted by instrumented processes.
Run the target application. In this case I ran terrain.exe.
Shutdown the profiler monitor with the following command: "vsperfcmd /shutdown". This command causes the background profiler monitor to shutdown and write out the "test.vsp" file.
Open the resultant "test.vsp" file in Visual Studio 2017. Even though the VSP file was created with the monitor from VS2013 with data from an app that was instrumented with the VSInstr.exe from VS2013, the VS2017 reader should be able to read the file just fine and display the profiling report.
An even easier workaround is to change the toolset to VS2015 or VS2017. In this case the toolsets produce the binaries and PDBs that the VS2017 version of VSInstr.exe can instrument. In your sample project, after I change the toolset, everything from the IDE works to do the instrumentation profiling. Of course, I believe you already know of this workaround, but the difficulty with this one is that the newer toolset may not be able to cleanly build the project and the resultant binary uses a different CRT so has potentially different behavior based on the version of the compiler and CRT or other related toolset libraries. To just get profiling to work, it may not be worth the extra work to make the newer toolset cleanly build and the risk involved in any newer libraries, etc.

Please let me know if you could get the above workaround to work for you. If you can't, I'll be happy to dig in further.

At the present time, we have no plans to make the VS2017 VSInstr.exe work to instrument apps that are built with the VS2013 toolset. We will keep this in mind in the future, however. If we make improvements to VSInstr.exe this is one of the improvements we will consider. Thank you for helping to make Visual Studio even better.

Allen Denver

Visual Studio

ldrs  Allen Denver [MSFT] · Jul 22 at 5:37 AM
Hi Allen,

I tried the suggested workaround and have made one minor correction for step 3, since it wanted OUTPUT instead of OUT: vsperfcmd /start:trace /output:test.vsp

After this, I am able to open the resulting vsp in a new VS version, so the workaroud works.

Thank you very much for the investigation and workaround!

Comment: Do we get only stand alone Performance tools for VS2013 or do we need to install the enitre 2013 suite to get the performance tool?