# How to get profiling data on cache misses in Unity?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, profiling

**I'm searching for a way to get profiling data on cache misses for my Unity project.**

I already searched for visual studio tools that do have these stats. I can see Visual studio has tools for .NET applications that shows cache misses (like what's described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/cpu-and-windows-counters?view=vs-2017), like its Performance Wizard, but they are always grayed out for my Unity project.

I tried attaching Visual Studio's performance tools to my running Unity projects, but I can't seem to find the data I'm looking for.

Unfortunately, Unity's profiler doesn't seem to show the cache misses stats I'm looking for.

I’m using mono but am open to switching to IL2CPP if that can help, I’m mainly exploring unity performance at this point.

I would like to remove guess work from my optimisations. Is there anything I missed?

**Edit 1:**
Here's what I tested.

I created a build of my test project with IL2CPP selected in the player options

In visual studio, I went to Debug/Performance Profiler, I selected the "Executable" target and used the option "Performance Wizard".
After clicking "Start" I used the option "Instrumentation", clicked next, used "An executable" for the application I want to profile, clicked next, selected my created build's .exe, clicked next and finish.

I then get a failure saying:

```
Profiling started.
Instrumenting <my path to my exe> in place
Info VSP3049: Small functions will be excluded from instrumentation.
Microsoft (R) VSInstr Post-Link Instrumentation 15.8.18219.1 x86
Unable to obtain debug information. Link with the /PROFILE linker switch.
PRF0002: Instrumentation failed with these options: /u "<my path to exe> /excludesmallfuncs.  Please check the output window for additional details.
Data written to <my path>200126(5).vsp.
Profiling finished.
Profiling complete.
```

I tried looking into [Error VSP1011: Unable to obtain debug information. Link with the /Profile linker switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45718339/error-vsp1011-unable-to-obtain-debug-information-link-with-the-profile-linker) but I'm not sure it's relevant.

I installed VS2013 and tried the same steps and it gave me the same errors.

Comment: Are you using Mono or IL2CPP?

Comment: I’m experimenting with performance in Unity, so I’m open to switch. I was using mono

Comment: You should probably use IL2CPP. It's supposed to be faster since there is no JIT and it's optimized C++.
Then, for your code optimization, you probably shouldn't be focusing on cache misses. Try exploring new algorithms for your solutions, doing more caches, avoid garbage collection and such.
To remove guess work you can simply profile (or deep profile) your game and check the CPU/GPU timings and which functions are spending too much of your CPU time. Then you can focus on those functions and optimize them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already know how to optimise and profile CPU/GPU using Unity's profiler. However, knowing that a cache access is ~25x faster than a memory access, if I want to get even more juice out of my game I'd like to know how to go to the next step and see where I can get that extra performance.
My question is not how I can optimize my game in general, it's really how can I do cache misses analysis with Unity

Comment: Try profiling using IL2CPP project

Comment: I edited my post with what I've tried after your suggestion

Comment: I tried with VS2013 and I'm getting the same error. 
Something interesting is when I run the performance wizard, the CPU sampling option isn't grayed out. However when I use that option I get a Kernel-Power critical error and my computer reboots...
I'm running Windows 7, could there be some incompatibility? I'm just throwing stuff out there, I have no clue what to do here :(

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a good tool for this.

Looks like Intel's VTune is pretty easy to use and gives good info. For sure it's sampling and doesn't show the exact information, but it gives me hotspots of things to investigate.