# Instrumenting a Rust executable for profiling

Tags: windows, rust, profiling

I'm trying to analyze the performance of a Rust executable on Windows, but cannot seem to instrument the executable image using the [VSInstr.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/vsinstr) tool.

To get started I set up a binary cargo package (`cargo new --bin sample`), and enabled generation of a PDB by adding

```
[profile.release]
debug = true
```

to the standard Cargo.toml file. Executing `cargo build --release` produces both *sample.exe* and *sample.pdb*. Navigating to *target/release* and executing `vsinstr sample.exe` produces the following diagnostic (VS2017 and VS2019, respectively):

> ```
> Error VSP1011: Unable to obtain debug information. Link with the /Profile linker switch.
> ```

> ```
> Unable to obtain debug information. Link with the /PROFILE linker switch.
> ```

Fair enough, so let's add the following *.cargo/config* file:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-args=/PROFILE"]
```

to pass the required flag to the linker. Running `cargo build --release` again produces the same artifacts, *sample.exe* and *sample.pdb*. Attempting to instrument the image using `vsinstr sample.exe` now produces the following diagnostic (VS2017 and VS2019, respectively):

> ```
> Error VSP1033: The file '<path>\sample.exe' does not contain a recognized executable image.
> ```

> ```
> The file does not contain a recognized executable image.
> ```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here, or how to further diagnose the core issue.

- Is there something wrong with what I'm doing?
- Am I running into a limitation of rustc/Clang?
- Most importantly, how do I fix the issue?

---

Notes:

The [/PROFILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/profile-performance-tools-profiler) linker option is documented to be *"available only in Enterprise (team development) versions"*. That information seems outdated. Using the option on a C++ application in Visual Studio 2019 Community had the desired effect.

I've verified, that the `/PROFILE` flag gets passed to the linker by adding the `-Z print-link-args` flag to the `rustflags` in *.cargo/config* to see the actual linker command line.

Profiling any given Rust application in sample mode (CPU Usage) from the Visual Studio IDE works as long as the respective PDB is available. That's helpful, but I'd really like to get accurate call graphs, so instrumentation is required.

Alongside *VSInstr.exe*, Visual Studio also ships a binary called *vsinstr.legacy.exe*, that apparently dumps out more information. Running this against the Rust executable produces a list of warnings that have the following shape:

> ```
> Warning VSP2005: Internal instrumentation warning: Block start at 1400016D9 is inside instruction at 1400016D8. Removed.
> ```

The addresses in all messages differ exactly by 1, which looks an awful lot like an off-by-one error, presumably in the code that produces the PDBs.

Comment: See https://nnethercote.github.io/perf-book/profiling.html, https://docs.rs/tracing/0.1.28/tracing/attr.instrument.html, https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/p6nvgy/how_to_profile_rust_programs_using_visual_studio/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45718339/error-vsp1011-unable-to-obtain-debug-information-link-with-the-profile-linker. Also, when you get the `The file does not contain a recognized executable image.` error, can the program still execute normally?

Comment: @sol The executable runs fine. The issue appears to be caused by a (partially) invalid PDB. I have not been able to determine the root cause yet (it's either in rustc or LLVM), and [the issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/88721) I've filed hasn't produced any insights so far. The list of profilers doesn't help much. They are either Linux-based, or require the same PDB information that's broken. The tracing crate doesn't help either since I'm profiling foreign code. The reddit thread recommends using snapshot profiling, which is far less accurate.

Comment: The final Q&A also doesn't apply. That issue is cause by the VS 2013 toolset which Rust isn't using, neither directly nor indirectly.